# Using REGEX to disregard emails but make links clickable

Tags: regex, coffeescript

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to make a REGEX expression be able to both

1. Recognize emails and disregard them
2. Make links clickable

Right now I have this:

```
body = data.body.replace(/</, '&lt;')
.replace(/>/, '&gt;')
.replace ///
  ((http|https):\/\/)?
  [\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?
  ///gi, (match)->
    url = if match.indexOf('http') == 0 then match else "http://#{match}"
    "<a href='#{url}' target='_blank'>#{match}</a>"
```

What this does is find a link, and make an `<a href=` call on the URL, while making just the root of the site visible to make it clean. The issue is it's also doing it for e-mails. Any ideas?

The `data.body` contains a chat message. For example,

`thanks, matt. my email is johnsmith@gmail.com`

Comment: Can you add an example block of text you'd be searching, and examples of what you want to match/not match? Just as a heads up, URL and email matching is a tricky problem.

Comment: @Mathletics sure, updated. Hope that helps a little.